# How do I modify a variable name?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, naming

I may be asking this wrong, overlooking something really simple, or just be trying to do the impossible.. Or I may be asking the wrong question to get the answer I need from the search, so please accept my apologies if I have missed the answer somewhere..

I am trying to rename a session variable.. I have a script that contains multiple includes to other scripts that create data tables of users history of payment. There is XML sent back from my cart that is used to update the databases that the information is drawn from. This script checks the session variables (IE: $_SESSION['PAYMENT1'], $_SESSION['PAYMENT2'], etc..) and if there is a value it calls the correct script to add a table below the previous payment. All of this works great, but when a new payment is received, i would like to update the view to show the most recent payment. It is working, but only after a logout/re-login. is there a way to dynamically add the nnumber to the name (IE: $_SESSION['PAYMENT*change this to correct number*'])
I have done this using PHP vars echoed into HTML code, but I need to do it in a PHP script.. I know I can with Java, but the powers that be do not want to use that "in case they turn off java".. not that I know of anyone who disables Java anymore..

Comment: as in `$_SESSION['PAYMENT{$var}'] = "Something";`?

Comment: `$_SESSION['payment'][]=$xxxx` sounds like you should just use a multidimensional array

Comment: The language you are referring to is named "Javascript", not "Java".

Comment: How about just creating a variable in which you always put the latest value?

Comment: Jon, that is exactly what I need to do.. Dagon, that seems like that is the only way I can nake it happen, if not then I guess Arianes idea will work too... I am not sure why the simple is so easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count the size of $_SESSION

```
$s=count($_SESSION);
```

and whenever a new payment in made just create a new session variable-\

```
$_SESSION['payment'.$s+1]="";
```

hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: This seems to work the best to answer what I asked! That said, after looking a little deeper I think an array is the CORRECT way to go.. So this is my temporary fix as I look into how to implement arrays for these functions.. Thank you everyone for your input!!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it that way in php, instead you should use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

If you store your data in an array you can do it all like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['PAYMENTS'] as &$payment) {
    $payment += 5;
}
```

You can store your data in an array by doing `$_SESSION['PAYMENTS'][0] = $myNewPayment`

Comment: ALWAYS `unset($payment)` immediately after the loop if you create a reference! Otherwise strange side effects will occur!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array! `$_SESSION['payment'][1]` etc.